# How do I access content created by React from a Python scraper script?

Tags: python, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple script with python that will go through my Facebook activity log and delete some content to make my clean up much easier. My previous experience with similar tasks makes it pretty simple to go through the dom and automate interaction.

However, the actual `unlike` or `delete` buttons don't appear to be in the HTML source of the downloaded page. I assume because they're created dynamically by React. I just need to know how to interact with these elements.

How do you target a React generated element that isn't in the DOM with a python crawler?

Comment: React is a Javascript library, it creates DOM elements by executing javascript. You need a way to run a fully functional browser environment with a real DOM and a real JS interpreter. The word you're looking for is "headless browser": https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers